# Remove 'TEXT' from click (python module) help menu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python's click library to parse arguments for my command-line program. I have an option as shown:

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option('--foo', '-f', help='Foo help message')
def main(foo):
    print(foo)


main()
```

Now, whenever I call for the help menu with 'python myscript.py --help'

```
Options:
--foo, -f TEXT  Foo help message
--help            Show this message and exit.
```

I don't want it to display 'TEXT' in the help menu next to my foo option. How do I change/get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `metavar` to control how a value is repeseneted in the help page. So to hide TEXT you can set it to `''`

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option('--foo', '-f', metavar='', help='Foo help message')
def main(foo):
    print(foo)


main()
```

Output:

```
Options:
  -f, --foo   Foo help message
  --help      Show this message and exit.
```